# ie8 ignores all my font-face declarations

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, font-face, compass-sass

I've google and searched on stackoverflow for a couple of hours now, still not working .
My problem is ie8 completely ignores my font-face declarations, when I go to the network tab, it doesn't even require the font from the server (I don't see errors but I don't see the call neither). Anyone has an idea?
I'm using compass:

```
@include font-face(
  fontello,
  font-files(
      "fontello.eot?98351649",
      "fontello.eot?98351649?iefix",
      "fontello.woff?98351649",
      "fontello.ttf?98351649",
      "fontello.svg?98351649#fontello"
  ),
  $weight:normal,
  $style:normal
);
```

which compiles to:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: fontello;
  src: url('/static/fonts/fontello.eot?98351649') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/static/fonts/fontello.eot?98351649?iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/static/fonts/fontello.woff?98351649') format('woff'), url('/static/fonts/fontello.ttf?98351649') format('truetype'), url('/static/fonts/fontello.svg?98351649#fontello') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

and then:

```
body {
  font-family: fontello, Arial, Helvetica, Verdana !important;
}
```

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fontello has some known issues with IE8 (and IE8 has a problem with custom fonts for that matter).

Check a similar issue here: https://github.com/fontello/fontello/issues/70 and check a possible answer here: http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/ie8-and-fontello/

My advice, as a fellow developer, is: you either ditch IE8, or you ditch Fontello and go for the classic approach, with images / sprites.

Comment: I used fontello here as an example, but I also need another font on the site and that can't be replaced with sprites. That font works fine on ie on an old site: http://www.graubuenden.ch/ (the menu bar), but for some reason it doesn't on my site. I downloaded the font and tried copy/pasting the font-face declaration from that site. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
I had to move fontello.eot out of the font-files parenthesis in the compass declaration:

```
@include font-face(
  "fontello",
  font-files(
      "fontello.eot?98351649?iefix",
      "fontello.woff?98351649",
      "fontello.ttf?98351649",
      "fontello.svg?98351649#fontello"
  ),
  "fontello.eot?98351649"
);
```